# Should I install VS 2017 Community and VS 2017 Enterprise side by side?

Tags: windows-10, performance, vmware-workstation, visual-studio

I am running Windows 10 x64 in VMWare where I use Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition for development purposes.

However I need to use some features of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition for special cases. I am looking at installing it.

My question is

1. Will installing VS 2017 Enterprise side by side with VS 2017 Community have any negative **performance** impact on my machine *even* if I use them *one at a time* for my development purposes?

OR

2. Should I use a separate virtual machine for VS 2017 Enterprise installation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC Enterprise contains all features. Why bother installing both when you have an Enterprise license?

Comment: Community is lighter is my machine

Comment: Space is not a concern. RAM and CPU is. Enterprise has more feature sets which require more ram and cpu processing. Needless to say I'm constrained on RAM and CPU